# Invalid localized chars in a text file

Tags: c, unicode, wchar-t, c89

I learn the C language. I need to create some text file with Unicode data. I have wrote such code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    wchar_t *s1 = L"Привет, мир!\n";
    wchar_t *s2 = L"Hello, World!";

    FILE *fp = fopen("./hello.txt", "w");

    fputws(s1, fp);
    fputws(s2, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But I get such result:

```
??????, ???!
Hello, World!
```

Why I don't get the Russian chars?

Comment: Please explain how you are viewing the file

Comment: I open it in gedit (Linux).

Comment: What encoding does gedit think the file is? Does it match the actual encoding? And if you are using Linux then I suspect that UTF-8 would be the preferred encoding to use.

Comment: When I press "save as", then I see the "Utf-8".

Comment: If You want UTF-8, write code in UTF-8 and use plain char. It will work. The using of wchar_t for "Unicode" is only a Microsoft implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you are having a problem with the locales in the terminal you are running the program. If it is so, you only have to set the locale like this:

`setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"");`

More information [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale)